# Datastructure to mimick Performance Monitor

Tags: c#, wpf, data-structures

I'm developing a custom monitoring service for our software which is spread out on several systems. We've decided to present the data like the Report view in the Performance Monitor.
[image]

To store the data, we use a very simple database table which only keep the latest value:

```
|Server|Object|Instance|Query|Value|
```

So each value is uniquely identifiable through Server, Object, Instance and Query.
An example might be

```
|Server| Object     |Instance| Query     |Value|
+------+------------+--------+-----------+-----+
| Srv1 | Disk       |   C:/  | TotalSize |500GB|
| Srv1 | Disk       |   C:/  | FreeSpace | 50GB|
| Srv1 | Disk       |   C:/  | UsedSpace |450GB|
| Srv1 | Disk       |   C:/  | VolumeLbl |  OS |
| Srv1 | Disk       |   D:/  | TotalSize |900GB|
| Srv1 | Disk       |   D:/  | FreeSpace |700GB|
| Srv1 | Disk       |   D:/  | UsedSpace |200GB|
| Srv1 | Disk       |   D:/  | VolumeLbl | Data|
| Srv1 | Performance|   ---  | CpuUsage  | 12% |
| Srv1 | Performance|   ---  | MemUsage  | 34% |
| Srv1 | Performance|   ---  | Processes | 64  |
```

Now we want to transform this into this:

```
Srv1
    Disk             
                     C:/        D:/  
        TotalSize    500GB      900GB
        FreeSpace    50GB       700GB
        UsedSpace    450GB      200gb
        VolumeLbl    OS         Data            

    Performance      
        CpuUsage     12%
        MemUsage     34%
        Processes    64
```

I'm at a loss as to what kind of structure I should use to store this.
It's easy to see that the Objects (Disk and Performance) is a sub-object of Server, but should Query be a sub object of Instance, or Object? In a regular table, each row is an object, and the columns are sub-objects of that row. But I feel it should be the other way around in this case, as the Queries are sub-objects of the Instances. And should Values just be stored under the Query or Instance, or should it be some kind of two-dimensional array?
So basically, what's the cleanest, most efficiently and best practice way to implement this?

We are using WPF, and being able to bind to the structure is pretty much a requirement. So implementing this using only ObservableCollections or custom structures with CollectionChanged is a second challenge.

Comment: I don't see anything complicated about this.. Why don't you create a ViewModel that represents the data in the way you want to show it on screen and then fill that with the query results?

Comment: For several reasons we don't use MVVM. And the views are dynamic, and I have no idea how to represent those dynamic columns at runtime. It might be that I'm over complicating things, though...

Comment: What do you mean by "views are dynamic"? do you instantiate all UIElements at runtime by code? that is completely unnecessary in WPF. I don't see any valid reason not to use MVVM (in WPF, don't know in other frameworks)

Comment: The reason for not using MVVM is that the application was not built using MVVM from the start and we have not time nor the manpower to justify rewriting something that's working. And by dynamic, I mean that Objects, Instances and Queries are all retrieved from the database: An object can have several queries and instances, and some queries might not even be valid for some instances. And if I would use MVVM, how would the model, and view model look like? I'm looking for the answer to the question "How should I store this?", not which framework should I use.

Comment: I still don't see the difficulty.. just create a ServerViewModel (call it otherwise if you don't want to call it a ViewModel) and it will have a list of objects, each of which may have an Instance, a Query and a Value..